# aiy.led and aiy.board modules do not exist

Tags: module, voice, google-aiy

I am trying to import a module to control the LED in the button of the voice AIY. I have version 2 of the kit. Using both the [v2 instructions](https://aiyprojects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aiy.leds.html) and the [v1 instructions](https://aiyprojects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aiy.board.html#aiy.board.Led), I get an `ImportError` when trying to import the packages. The v2 instructions say to run `from aiy.leds import Leds, Color`, and the v1 instructions say to use `from aiy.board import Board, Led`

Am I incorrectly trying to import the module, or missing it entirely? If it is missing, can I download the necessary module, or do I have to re-flash the image entirely?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/aiy/projects-python/src $ python3 main.py

Importing packages...
        Importing LED...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 454, in <module>
    from aiy.board import Board, Led
ImportError: No module named 'aiy.board'

pi@raspberrypi:/opt/aiy/projects-python/src $ sudo nano main.py
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/aiy/projects-python/src $ python3 main.py

Importing packages...
        Importing LED...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 458, in <module>
    from aiy.leds import Leds, Color
ImportError: No module named 'aiy.leds'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in the "src" directory check if directory "aiy" is present there.
If not, that's the problem. If yes, check that "board.py and leds.py and **init**.py are present within "aiy".

If not, you need to install those with apt-get install commands. See

```
https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/blob/v20181116/HACKING.md
```

for additional details. The Google repo must be present to find these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found the problem, which was actually that the package had a different name because I used the SD card image provided with the kit, so the module was named aiy.vision.leds. After updating, though, I might have bricked the kit, so I may need to do this after I re-image it.